# Angular.js beginner what version should I use?

Tags: angularjs

I am starting to integrate Angular.js into my web project.

I see on the Angular.js download page they have version 2.0.0-snapshot although I don't think version 2 has been formally released.

From the looks of the download page I think the last stable version was 1.4.7. Is that the last stable version?

And also what is recommended? Should start with version 2 or version 1.4.7 (keeping in mind a I am complete beginner).

Comment: this gets asked constantly and whether or not you want to gamble on a release that hasn't happened or not is up to you

Comment: Thank you. That's actually a good answer. It gives me a realisation that there has been nothing said to give confidence in the current form of version 2.0 which means exactly as you said... it's a "gamble". Appreciate this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2 is currently in Developer Preview. Angular 1.X is recommended for production applications.

That said. It's pretty important to remember that Angular 2 is basically a completely different framework with **little-to-no backwards compatibility**. When we all do switch (and we will someday), we'll have to start with a fresh plugin community, or wait until developers choose to update their modules to include an Angular 2 version.

> Our goal with Angular 2 is to make the best possible set of tools for building web apps not constrained by maintaining backwards compatibility with existing APIs. - Angular Blog

I think the time to migrate will be around 6 months after a production release of Angular 2. That will give the developer community time to catch up and give the framework time to mature in the real world.

Comment: Or, since you have to rewrite to another framework anyway, it might make sense to go to a different one at that point.

Comment: Spot on answer. Unless your application is terribly basic, I doubt you'll be able to get it of the ground with Angular 2 - ngResource awaits community contribution and the router is often broken with frequent changes to the API. Even if my app was to be released in 2017 I wouldn't put my chips on Angular 2 at the moment.

Comment: thanks guys. Appreciate this feedback. It's clear to me which direction I should take.